# Failure 3706 Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the word 'tbuild'

Tags: teradata

I'm getting this error message every time I try to run the very, very simple script from [this tutorial](http://usefulfreetips.com/Teradata-SQL-Tutorial/teradata-parallel-transporter-tpt-basics-example-and-syntax/). I'm pretty new to Teradata, please help:

> BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command: tbuild -f
>   /root/multiloadtest/TPT_Load.tpt; tbuild -f
>   /root/multiloadtest/TPT_Load.tpt; tbuild -f
>   /root/multiloadtest/TPT_Load.tpt; $
>   *** Failure 3706 Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the word 'tbuild'. Statement# 2, Info =9
>   *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`tbuild` is a TPT (Teradata Parallel Transporter) CLI, in the same manner `bteq` is a query CLI.
You execute it from the command line, not from `bteq`.